# Change Style of Selection.ColumnDifferences

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to add a quick access icon to the Excel toolbar to perform the F5, Special, Column differences task.

How do I change the highlight style of that action? Currently it is a sort of greyish white and if there are multiple differences in a column (50+ rows) muliple differences are not easily recognizable.

I tried this modification but the highlight will stay after another cell is selected.

```vb
Sub column_difference()

    Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select
    Selection.Style = "Bad"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bad" is the name of a built-in style. If you change the name of the style to "Good" you will get another colour. If you were to create a style called "MyStyle" you could specify the colour yourself.

There is a "Styles" menu on the `Home` ribbon. On that menu there is a drop-down button called "Cell Styles". At the bottom of the dialog box that opens when you click that button there is a button called "New cell style". In the dialog box behind that button you can create a style of your own and call it "MyStyle". After that you can use the "MyStyle" name in your code. You can save the style with your workbook.

Needless to say, your code will only work in workbooks where `MyStyle` style exists. On the other hand, a `Style` is just a collection of specific cell formats. In the style setup dialog box you find a list of all the format properties a style affects. Your interest seems to focus on the cell's fill colour. Therefore, instead of changing the selected cells' *Style* you could just change their fill colour.

Select any cell and colour it the way you want. Then, with that cell still selected, enter `? ActiveCell.Interior.Color` in the VBE's Immediate window. This will give you the number of your chosen colour.  Then modify your code using that number.

```
Sub column_difference()

    Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select
    Selection.Interior.Color = 255

End Sub
```

`255` = vbRed. The above code will change the the Selection's fill colour to red but leave the font colour as it was before.  The extra line `Selection.Font.Color = vbWhite` would change that, too. If you created *MyStyle* with those two properties you could apply both commands with a single, and shorter, line of code. `Selection.Style = "Normal"` would change everything back to the original, i.e. what that cell's formatting was when the worksheet was first created.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Will try different styles. But is there a way to make it temporary? So that after code is run the cells are highlighted temporarily in e.g. red but when the user continues the highlight disappears?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You would have to define the meaning of "when the user continues". If you define it as "when the user clicks anywhere on the worksheet [other than a highlighted cell]" you could use the `SelectionChange` event to remove all highlights. It takes a lot of defining of rules for this, depending on your workflow and preference. You would have to start a new thread supported by your own effort.